# Unique_ptr with custom deleter

Tags: c++

Here is a MRE of my code:

```
#include <memory>

struct Deleter
{
    void operator() (A* a) {}
};

class A
{
    A(int a) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A, Deleter> unique = std::make_unique<A, Deleter>(5);
}
```

I get this error:

```
error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>> std::make_unique<A,Deleter,0>(Deleter &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'Deleter &&'
```

How should I call `A` constructor with `std::make_unique` when I use a custom deleter like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `std::make_unique` with a custom deleter. You’ll need to use the regular constructor instead:

```
auto unique = std::unique_ptr<A, Deleter>(new A(5), Deleter());
```

Of course this will still require you to fix the rest of your code: make the constructor of `A` public, and declare `A` before `Deleter`. And you’d need to replace `new A(…)` by the proper construction that matches the custom `Deleter`.

And it’s worth noting that this might leak memory if the `Deleter` constructor throws, so you need to make sure that it doesn’t do that.